# Can I convert a video download link to a online video streaming?

Tags: conversion, video-streaming

If I have a video download link, can I convert it to a link that I can watch the video online by clicking on it? Or is there any website to put a video download URL and watch the video online?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you would like to watch the video immediately, rather
than wait for the download to complete.

It is possible to watch the video *while downloading it*, this way:

- Start the download in Chrome (or any browser)
- Go to Downloads, right-click the link to copy the link address
- Launch your media player on your computer or mobile device
- Open the network streaming feature and paste the link
- Click play.

Here is where network streaming is found in some popular media players:

- VLC media player (Windows): Media > Open Network Stream or Ctrl+N.
- Windows media player (Windows): Press Ctrl+U.
- MX Player (Android):  Three-dots menu > Network Stream.
- VLC (Android): Sidebar menu > Open MRL.
- VLC (iOS): Sidebar menu > Open network stream.

(This answer is based on the article
[How To Play Download Links Instead of Waiting For Download](https://vintaytime.com/how-to-play-download-links/).)